# Impala convert string to timestamp always returns to NULL

Tags: sql, impala

I want to convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss string to date format.

```
select to_timestamp('19/05/2010 20:03:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

this is not converting the string to timeformat and always returns me NULL.

Please guide where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use correct format.

```
 select to_timestamp('19/05/2010 20:03:55', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') as ts;
```

[image: Output]
The pattern string supports the following subset of Java SimpleDateFormat.

```
Pattern Description
y       Year
M       Month
d       Day
H       Hour
m       Minute
s       Second
S       Fractional second
```

A date string including all fields could be 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS', 'MMM dd, yyyy HH.mm.ss (SSSSSS)' or other combinations of placeholders and separator characters.

Comment: The pattern letters are by no means specific to the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. See the Unicode [Date Field Symbol Table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table).

Comment: May be, but this above `SimpleDate` format info is in their official site so i posted it here. Also this code works in my version. Not sure about new simple data format rules.